# mail app fails to login for google mail

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

My problem with using the email app started today, after macOS update to version 10.14.4.

The problem is email (and calendar) app fail to log into google.   I have entered my google email address, password and 2 factor authentication code at least 7 times now.

Things I have tried:

1. delete my accounts and reenter the account
2. log into google using both safari and chrome

Totally lost as what to try next.

Thnx

Comment: This is a known defect and it's being [widely discussed on various Apple sites](https://9to5mac.com/2019/03/26/gmail-macos-10-14-4-sign-in-fail/).  There's no proposed solution or fix by Apple at this time.

Comment: @fsb thnx.  I didnt find that when I searched.  That does sound like my problem other than I do not see "null" account.